# Express.js static files won't load up correctly

Tags: node.js, express

my app was working fine as I was routing all requests to "/:postName" to deliver back the corresponding html file. But after I switched to use the routes of form "/posts/postName" the links to the html files just broke down as no more css was being shown.

This is a snippet from server.js

```
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
addRoutesToPosts(Post);

async function addRoutesToPosts(model) {
var result = await model.find().exec();
console.log(__dirname);
result.forEach((post) => {
    app.get(`/posts${post.linkToPost}`, (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + `/static pages/posts${post.linkToPost}.html`);
    })
});
}
```

and a css link tag in one html document as an example

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Contact-Form-Clean.css">
```

When I tried to inspect and follow the css link in html rendered by the browser, I get this error. Apparently the root for static files isn't being taken into account here, because it is supposed to fetch the css file at /public/assets/css/..., posts is the directory where the html file resides.

Please let me know if I'm missing or not fully understanding something here. Thanks!

[Cannot GET /posts/assets/css/Contact-Form-Clean.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0lBx.jpg)

Comment: using a base URL when calling static things like css or etc, is a solution.

Comment: Read this [other answer](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) from earlier in the day and see if that applies to your situation.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I was able to solve this by adding `app.use("/posts", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`